# WebGL: Is it forbidden to bind the same uniform in a vertex shader and fragment shader?

Tags: webgl, opengl-es-2.0

I am porting an OpenGL framework to JavaScript using Emscriten.

The state is stored in a uniform struct:

```
struct UniformState {
    ...
    mat4 modelviewprojection_matrix; 
    mat4 modelview_matrix;
    mat3 normal_matrix; 
    mat4 texture_matrix;
    ...
};
```

that I'd like to access in both the vertex and the fragment shaders as:

```
uniform UniformState GLUP;
```

when I do that, I get an error at link time:

```
Uniform `GLUP`is not linkable between attached shaders
```

Is it forbidden to bind the same uniform in the vertex shader and fragment shader ?

(if it is forbidden, then clearly I can declare two different sets of uniform variables for each shader, but I'd prefer to have only one, since it makes the code cleaner / simpler, this is why I'm asking in case there
is something special to do to make it possible).

Comment: its been a long time since i've done this. i think you can pass uniforms from the vertex shader to the fragment shader

Comment: Please show code that setups the uniform, fetches location and sends it for the drawcall. Seems that sending it the wrong way might be the issue. Any way, you can output uniform value from vertex shader to be input to the fragment shader (varying var), if all else fails.

Comment: The error occurs at shader link time, so it cannot be caused by the way uniform locations are fetched and uniforms are specified (it is done after).

Comment: You might have different precision settings for vertex and fragment shader. Note that the default precisions are different between shader types.

Comment: Yes it works, it was because I was using mediump in the FS, setting precision as highp fixed the problem. What are the consequences of having the FS set to highp ? Does it decrease performances on mobile devices ?

Comment: Another "gotcha": if there are ints in the uniform variables, you need also to do "precision highp int;" (as well as "precision highp float;"), it is worth mentioning because I lost 2 hours scratching my head (and the error message I got from the GLSL compiler was not very explicit)

Comment: Finally, I reverted back to two separate sets of uniforms, and kept default mediump precision for the FS, else my WebGL program does not work on Mac OS/X.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Seems to work for me.

Note as Reto mentioned if I don't set the precision I get a link error

```js
"use strict";
var gl = document.createElement("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var program = twgl.createProgramFromScripts(gl, ["vs", "fs"], [], [], log);
log("--done--");

function log(msg) {
  var elem = document.createElement("pre");
  elem.appendChild(document.createTextNode(msg));
  document.body.appendChild(elem);
}
```

```html
  <script id="vs" type="notjs">
struct Test {
  vec4 color;
  vec4 mult;
};

uniform Test test;
  
attribute vec4 position;

void main() {
  gl_Position = position * test.mult;
}
  </script>
  <script id="fs" type="notjs">
precision highp float;

struct Test {
  vec4 color;
  vec4 mult;
};

uniform Test test;

void main() {
  gl_FragColor = test.color;
  }
  </script>
  <script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: What should be done for GPUs that dont support highp for fragment shaders? https://github.com/CesiumGS/cesium/issues/817 https://github.com/CesiumGS/webglreport/blob/master/webglreport.js#L120

Comment: declare the uniforms to be mediump in both shaders as in `struct  Test { mediump vec4 color; mediump vec4 mult; }`. But be aware of the limits of `mediump`. For colors you're fine but for say point light calcultions mediump does not have enough precision for the monst common ways of calculating point lights so whatever your shaders are doing if the user has a phone that doesn't support highp you might just have to use different shaders all togehter.

Comment: So would you say the preferable way is to check if highp is valid, if so, use highp for both  (by dynamically modifying the shader text), if not, then will mediump be automatically set in the vertex shader, or would I have to automatically set it to "mediump" in the vertex one also?

Comment: they have to be the same in both shaders. As for checking you can use `#ifdef GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` in the shader itself or you can check with JavaScript with `getShaderPrecisionFormat`. It's up to you if you want to modify the shaders, use different shaders, use creative preprocessor macros, etc...

Comment: aha but what is the defualt in vertex shader? Is it highp? If so then in a device that doesnt support it would the default be mediump?

Comment: the default is always highp in the vertex shader and highp is supported in all GPUs in the vertex shader. It's only the fragment shader where highp is optional.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212400/discussion-between-bluejayke-and-gman).

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/issues/3059#issuecomment-619270233